# Object or property already exists error when trying to export-certificate from root store

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export my entire `Cert:\CurrentUser\Root\` certificate store to an .SST file. What am I doing incorrectly?

In an administrator's powershell - I'm using:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\Root\ | Export-Certificate -FilePath C:\certs\test.sst -Type SST.
```

It returns:

> Export-Certificate : The object or property already exists. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80092005) At line:1 char:46
>   + ... User\root | Export-Certificate -FilePath c:\certs\allcertasdfs.sst -T ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Export-Certificate], COMException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.ExportCertificateCommand

Comment: the 1st thing i would check is to see if the error msg is correct - that there is already such a file @ the destination. [*grin*]

Comment: I'm betting that you have a duplicate certificates, due to one or more certificates being stored into multiple physical stores (Registry/Enterprise/Third Party/etc.). Pipe to `Select -Unique` then to `Export-Certificate` and I'm guessing that you won't get that error.

Comment: That select tip did it - thanks!